# Why doesn't the Python sorted function take keyword order instead of reverse?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to understand the logic behind why Python implemented sorted in what seems to be a less-than-self-documenting manner.

If I want a list in descending order I do something like:

```
[something[x] for x in sorted(something, reverse=True)]
```

It seems like a far more self-documenting approach would be:

```
[something[x] for x in sorted(something, order="descending")]
```

I'm apologize if this isn't the right forum to ask an informational question. I have found stackoverflow to be one of the best places to get good information. Feel free to point me to where I should ask the question if this is not the appropriate place.

Comment: Why do you think the second is more self-documenting?

Comment: Given that there's a binary choice between ascending/descending, using a boolean here seems logical.

Comment: [Here](http://www.python.org/about/help/) you'll find several ways to contact Python people regarding bug fixes, documentation and other stuff. (Go to the bottom, _"Want to contribute?"_)

Comment: I don't know, I think `reverse=True` seems just as good. Since there are only 2 options, a boolean actually seems better to me

Comment: The only potential benefit of the second would be that you could omit the keyword with less risk of confusion. But the only reason to do that is to save keystrokes or bytes, and `"descending"` is a lot more keystrokes than `True`… Meanwhile, this would add a potential for error (what happens if you call it with "decsending"?)

Comment: If you can come up with `order='sideways'` sorting, I guess your way makes sense.

Comment: Depending on how the comparison is defined, reverse order may not actually be "descending".

Comment: And you can do useful things with the boolean like invert it with a `not` (say if you want to toggle between the two orders dynamically) rather than having to look string constants.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[x for x in sorted(something, reversed=True)]` or better: `list(sorted(something, reversed=True))`?

Comment: I think everyone's missing the OP's reasoning. `order="descending"` indicates what the order is; `reverse=True` just says that it's the opposite of the usual order.

Comment: `sorted(range(10), key=lambda n:-n, reverse=True)`.  In this context `order="descending"` would result in an ascending result.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input. I didn't get the actual question answered but learned a lot about the various trade-offs different people think about when the encounter a similar problem.

Comment: @bmacnaughton: If you want to know the actual reasons, see [the python-dev thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/53555) and [#823292](http://bugs.python.org/issue823292)… but briefly, while thinking of a solution to a stability problem with `a.sort(); a.reverse(); a.sort()` that no longer exists, Raymond Hettinger suggested a `reverse` parameter would fix it; he put it in his next patch; nobody had any serious objections; so that's it.

Comment: To go beyond that you'd have to go into Raymond's head. It could be because of any of the good reasons given above, or it could just be that he was staring at the word `reverse` in the problem so that naturally influenced the way he named the parameter (and once you call it `reverse` it's obviously going to be a boolean). He's pretty active on the lists, and has a good memory, so it might not be impossible to get the actual truth of the matter if you really care…

Answer (score 3):

I think a reason is that way is less prone to errors.

From the perspective of the programmer using the function: you can misspell "descending" to "decending", for example.

From the function maintainer perspective: you eliminate the need of raising additional exceptions from values other than "ascending" or "descending". When the options are only True or False, the chances of broken code decrease.

Additionally, there is a small performance bonus. Boolean comparisons will be a bit faster than string ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reverse=True` makes sense: the `key=` parameter in `sorted()` is used for defining an ordering, and the `reverse=` parameter indicates whether, with respect to that ordering, the output should be *ascending* or *descending* - given that there are only two possibilities it's logical to use a boolean parameter to control the behavior of `sorted()`. Besides, by clearly stating that only two values are possible, it won't be possible to pass a wrong value without the interpreter catching the error. In your proposed syntax, it'd be easy to misspell the correct parameter value.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment. (The fact that it starts off with "And what's wrong with…" is a pretty good indication of that.)

Comment: @abarnert it's an explanation of why the parameter was chosen as a boolean, that's an answer for me

Comment: It's an explanation of why _you_ think it _should_ be a boolean (unless you know this is what Raymond Hettinger was thinking).